# Не работает якорное меню

Tags: javascript, jquery

использую якорное меню на сайте. 
Использую такой вот код

```
 $("#site-navigation").on("click","a", function (event) {
        //отменяем стандартную обработку нажатия по ссылке
        event.preventDefault();

        //забираем идентификатор бока с атрибута href
        var id  = $(this).attr('href'),

        //узнаем высоту от начала страницы до блока на который ссылается якорь
            top = $(id).offset().top;

        //анимируем переход на расстояние - top за 1500 мс
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1500);
    });
```

На сайте много `section` и в каждом определенный ID , но проблема в том , что он бывает не достает до него ...скролит до половины или же вообще не к тому. Нажимаю на "портфолио" а скролит до "Блог" или тип этого. Почему так происходит?

Кое как он еще правильно крутит , когда  я нажму на li , он крутит до этого раздела , потом нажимаю опять на то же li , он крутит обратно вверх и потом можно нажимать на другое и то не со всеми так работает

Comment: Скорее всего прокручивает страницу к не правильной позиции из-за неправильно подсчета высоты. Какие-то элементы не принимаются в расчёт.

Comment: ну вот скорее всего , но я не понимаю почему  не принимаются

Comment: Согласно [документации](https://api.jquery.com/offset/) `jQuery не поддерживает получение координат смещения скрытых элементов или учет полей, установленных в <html>элементе документа`. И `размеры могут быть неправильными, когда страница масштабируется пользователем; браузеры не предоставляют API для обнаружения этого состояния.`. Смотрите какой Ваш случай...

Comment: как понять "страница масштабируется пользователем"?

Comment: Меняется масштаб шрифта, страницы, переписывается CSS стили пользовательскими.

Comment: ну к примеру я менял шрифты на свои, менял ```font-size, family```  ну и тд. мне надо было подогнать под мои размеры страницу... как исправить , чтобы он правильно вычислял? не знаете ? (

Comment: Попробуйте библиотеку [jquery.scrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo). Если она она будет работать корректно, то можете либо оставить её, либо посмотреть в её исходниках реализацию.